# Include file not found Arduino IDE

Tags: c, arduino

I'm abusing the hell out of the preprocessor to include a file that contains a series of WiFi Client writes to serve a webpage from an embedded device.

```
client.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
client.println("<meta charset='UTF-8'>");
client.println("<html>");
///etc
```

Obviously, I don't want 500 lines of that in the middle of my program.

So I've got this function:

```
void servePage ()
{
      client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
      client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
      #include "page"                                      
}
```

I'm using the Arduino IDE to do this and I can only seem to get the include to work with an absolute path, the relative path produces a "No such file or directory" error.

My `page` file is right next to my `*.ino` file in the working directory. Any ideas?

Comment: So the file is without extension and exactly “page”?

Comment: As said by @SamiKuhmonen, if you create a new file without extension with Arduino IDE, your file is called: "page.ino". Maybe `#include<page>` could work, but with `#include"page"` it search a filename.

Comment: The file is without extension and is called exactly "page" it's generated by another tool I wrote that converts my html to the c++ snippet I need. I'm not using Arduino out of choice and the hiding of so much functionality is already annoying the hell out of me

Comment: use .h extension

Comment: instead of #include, which still does code duplication (_bad_) in the background, you should rather call a function.

Comment: Please, don't do that. It's going to be impossible to mantain that code.

Comment: @Antonio I don't see how it's any less maintainable than simply copying the code into the source. My device doesn't have any flash memory to serve the HTML as a file, just the program memory. I normally wouldn't  do things this way but it's a one off thing so maintainability isn't really an issue on this occasion.

Comment: @datafiddler this include is only used once, I've extracted the source for actually serving the page so that I can work on the HTML file directly and then easily generate the snippet from that.

Comment: My main question is why Arduino IDE isn't picking up an include... The same thing happens if I try and include a custom header file in the same directory.